# What is this hot dog grilling machine called in everyday spoken English?

Tags: hot-dog

People love hot dogs.

What is this hot dog grilling machine called in everyday spoken English?

[image: Image of machine]

Comment: Native AmE speaker here. For real, I'd call that, "one of those hot-dog roller griller thingies". I'll try to give you a better answer after looking.

Comment: Not enough for an answer, but I think it's probably better to specify it as a "hot dog" grilling machine, rather than a "dog grilling machine", just to avoid misunderstandings when people don't have a visual.

Comment: Thank you for this question! It reminded me that I've intended for awhile to have it on my Amazon wish list [along with this](https://www.amazon.com/Kolice-Automatic-Machine-Doughnut-Counting/dp/B07FFS1W3G) - and then my kitchen will be complete!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After looking at a few examples on Amazon, I'd go with "hot dog roller grill". There isn't any correct or non-correct way to say it, but any American would know what you mean.

Comment: Just plain "roller grill" is probably enough; they're often used for other similarly-shaped food.

Comment: @Chrylis-onstrike- It looks like [Roller Grill](http://www.google.com/search?q=Roller%20Grill) is a brand, that makes all kinds of machines and accessories related to cooking. They do make the machine OP is asking for, and call it a [Professional Sausage Heater](https://www.rollergrill-international.com/en/professional-range/229/7/cooking/hot-dog-concepts/professional-sausage-heater-with-5-rollers-detail.html) with various number of rollers.

Comment: @LarsKristensen I've always heard it as "roller grill" when convenience stores are advertising the types of food cooked and served on them, so I suspect the name has become genericized, much like Xerox and Kleenex.

Comment: Reading the question in the sidebar: roller.  I personally wouldn't include the "grill".
  Source: Native speaker who often craves gas station hot dogs.